# Prove that $(\cap H_i) a= \cap Ha_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H_i$ be a family of subgroups of group $G$. Prove that for any $a\in G, (\cap H_i) a= \cap H_ia$.

I tried to use the fact the $H_ia\cap H_ja=\phi $ or $H_ia = H_ja$ but couldn't get to the result.

Comment: For clarification, this says the cosets of the intersection are equal to the intersections of the cosets?

Comment: @walkar yes thats what it says

Comment: What are the $a_i$ supposed to be? What is $H$ here? Is $H = \cap H_i$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I believe the asker meant $\cap H_i a$ not $\cap Ha_i$

Comment: @walkar That makes much more sense. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a simple subset argument.

$(\subseteq)$: Let $x \in (\cap H_i)a$. Thus, $x = ha$ for some $h \in \cap H_i$. What does that mean? Proceed from there.

$(\supseteq)$: Let $x \in \cap H_ia$. So for all relevant $i$, $x \in H_ia$. Take advantage of this.

Answer (score 1):

$g\in(\cap H_i)a$

$\Leftrightarrow ga^{-1}\in\cap H_i$

$\Leftrightarrow ga^{-1}\in H_i$ for each $i$

$\Leftrightarrow g\in H_{i}a$ for each $i$

$\Leftrightarrow g\in\cap(H_{i}a)$.

Hence $(\cap H_i)a=\cap(H_{i}a)$